# Computing surface area of a pyramid cut from another pyramid on the midpoints of sides of the bigger pyramid

Tags: geometry, area

Is it possible to compute the surface area of the blue pyramid in the picture, only given base area and height of the bigger pyramid? If not which additional parameters needed?.The base of pyramid passes through the midpoints of the sides of the bigger pyramid.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the information given is sufficient. If the lateral faces of the big pyramid is known, and the dimensions of its base known, and its later edges known, then the problem is easily solved.

Comment: Is AC perpendicular to BD?

Comment: Test it on GeoGebra.

Comment: You need more information that defines the base.

Comment: AC is not perpendicular to BD